# Adding Witness functionality Calling DocuSign

Tags: c#, docusignapi

I am using DocuSign(methods in DocuSign.eSign.dll) in c# to implement electronic signature functionality.
I want to add Witness feature similar to the way we do it physically when signing any document.

As per guidelines suggested by DocuSign ,I am using Signer Role as "Specify Recipients" and routing order as "2".

I am using SignHere object as 
below

```
Signer signer = new Signer      
{
     RoleName = "Specify Recipients",
     RoutingOrder = "2"
};
```

Whenever I call "CreateEnvelope" method exposed by DocuSign, It should give options in email to the recipient to add witness for his documents. Can I know what properties to be set of "Signer" object to achieve this. Or is there any other way to achieve this.

Answer (score 1):

You will need to add that recipient twice, in two separate roles.

A Signer is only able to act on the document. You'll need to create an Agent role for them to be able to specify later recipients.

If you haven't already, you'll also need to add the placeholder Witness role with no name/email defined so that they have a role to fill in.

```
        Signer signer = new Signer
        {
            Name = signerName,
            Email = signerEmail,
            RecipientId = "1",
            RoutingOrder = "1"
        };

        Agent agent = new Agent
        {
            Name = signerName,
            Email = signerEmail,
            RecipientId = "2",
            RoutingOrder = "2"
        };

        Signer witness = new Signer
        {
            RoleName = "Witness",
            RecipientId = "3",
            RoutingOrder = "3",
        };

        Signer[] signers = new Signer[] { signer, witness };
        Agent[] agents = new Agent[] { agent };

        Recipients recipients = new Recipients { Signers = new List<Signer>(signers), Agents = new List<Agent>(agents) };
```

with this setup, the recipient will first get an email invitation to sign the document. Once they complete that, they'll get another invitation to act as the Agent and specify the final recipient. Then the Witness that the user defined will receive their invitation.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I tried this but it's not helping .I am not using any template as it requires static document and I have to send documents dynamically using DocuSign.eSign.dll in c#.

Comment: in that case the RoleName parameter won't be relevant for the the Specify Recipients role, but it is necessary for the placeholder Witness role

Comment: I've updated my answer to show C# code, does this work for you?

Comment: Thanks a million Man..I was able to do it for Single signer. But I have a case where Two signer will sign for same document and they will have two witnesses respectively. In that case ,I am facing duplicate recipient error from DocuSign.. If You have any inputs for it thanks in advance.

Comment: I am able to do it for two signers for one document as well by having unique RecipientId  and RoutingOrder. Thanks.